# Passing string to QThread and out

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, pyqt5

This code is just an example using Google site, but I want it work for any JavaScript-enabled sites. So, I have: QPushButton object which is connected to getAnswer function which take text entered to QLineEdit object and (should) pass it to QThread, where this text should be used in search(text) function. Afterwards resulting text should appear in QLabel object. The question is: how do I pass this string to QThread and resulting string out?
The code below is expectedly crashed on

```
self.get_thread = getGoogle(self.text)
```

which is wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, \
    QLabel, QLineEdit, QGridLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QEventLoop, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from requests import get


class getGoogle(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.text=text

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def render(source_html):
        class Render(QWebEngineView):
            def __init__(self, html):
                self.html = None
                self.app = QApplication([])
                QWebEngineView.__init__(self)
                self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
                self.setHtml(html)
                while self.html is None:
                    self.app.processEvents(QEventLoop.ExcludeUserInputEvents | QEventLoop.ExcludeSocketNotifiers | QEventLoop.WaitForMoreEvents)
                self.app.quit()

            def _callable(self, data):
                self.html = data

            def _loadFinished(self):
                self.page().toHtml(self._callable)

        return Render(source_html).html

    def search(self, text):
        query=str(text)
        query = query.replace(" ", "+")
        url='https://www.google.com/search?q=' + query
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
        sample_html = get(url, headers=headers).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.render(sample_html), "html.parser")
        res = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'cwcot'})
        res = res.get_text()
        return res

    def run(self):
        result=self.search(text)
        self.emit(pyqtSignal('add_answer(QString)'), result)
        self.sleep(2)


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.sendButton = QPushButton('Ask', self)
        self.questionEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.answer=QLabel(self)
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(self.questionEdit, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.sendButton, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.answer, 2,0)
        self.sendButton.clicked.connect(self.getAnswer)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.resize(500, 100)
        self.show()

    def getAnswer(self):
        text = self.questionEdit.text()
        if len(text)>=1:
            self.get_thread = getGoogle(self.text)
            self.connect(self.get_thread, pyqtSignal("add_answer(QString)"), self.answer.setText)
            self.get_thread.start()
        else:
            self.answer.setText("Specify your question")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    my = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ypu are going to need to completely refactor your code. You are constructing New QApplications in the thread (probably causes the crash). You are constructing a GUI object in a thread (will cause a crash eventaully). You need to rewrite it so it doesn't do those things.

Comment: @three_pineapples if I use the code with only render() and search() function in a separate file it works fine, i.e. give desired results of the search() function. I know that two QApplication-s can't be run simultaneously, thus I hoped that running them in different threads would help. It's not true?
The thing is that I need a process which would render a resulting html from a JavaScript-enabled page.

Comment: By the way, maybe QProcess should help